Multi-dimensional scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint?
My linear constraint for scipy.optimize.minimize is
ones = np.ones_like(x)
np.outer(x, ones) - np.outer(ones, x) > something

where something is a given matrix.
(Mathematically, a_ij < x_i - x_j < a_ji).
How do I express this in terms of scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint which wouldn't accept a 3d "matrix" as a 1st argument?

I suspect your use of ones can be simplified to x[:,None]-x[None,:] (a broadcasted difference).

@hpaulj - nice trick, thank you, but how does this help my actual question?

What are the dimensions of x? If it's a two-dimensional matrix, np.outer(x, ones) - np.outer(ones, x) does not produce a 3D matrix, but a 2D matrix.

@hpaulj It can use a broadcast difference, but not that broadcast difference. Instead you would need np.subtract.outer(x.ravel(), x.ravel()) or equivalent.

@Reinderien: x is a vector (cf. a_ij < x_i - x_j < a_ji)

I'd suggest writing a loop that forms your constraint one row at a time.
If you want to add a constraint corresponding to a_ij < x_i - x_j < a_ji, you can do that by adding a vector to your constraint matrix which is all zeros, except for a one in the i'th position and a negative one in the j'th position. When SciPy takes the dot product of this vector with x, the result will be x_i - x_j.
You probably also want to avoid duplicate constraints. If you constrain both the value x_i - x_j and the value x_j - x_i, then those values are the same, except multiplied by -1. Having duplicate constraints can cause issues with some minimize methods due to low rank in the constraint matrix. In the below example, I have arbitrarily chosen that i < j for all constraints.
Here's an example.
import numpy as np
import scipy

something = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3).T
constraints_list = []
lb = []
ub = []
N = 3
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            # If i == j, then x_i - x_j = 0, and constraint is always satisfied or always violated
            continue
        if j > i:
            # If j > i, then this constraint duplicates another constraint.
            continue
        new_cons = np.zeros(N)
        new_cons[i] = 1
        new_cons[j] = -1
        constraints_list.append(new_cons)
        lb.append(something[i, j])
        ub.append(something[j, i])
constraints_array = np.array(constraints_list)
constraint = scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint(constraints_array, lb, ub)


# Compute constraint values in old way
x = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
print("Old constraint values")
ones = np.ones_like(x)
print(np.outer(x, ones) - np.outer(ones, x))

# Compute constraint values in new way
print("New constraint values (same as lower triangle of above array)")
print(constraint.A @ x)

print("Old constraint lower bound")
print(something)
print("New constraint lower bound (same as lower triangle of above array)")
print(constraint.lb)

Output:
Old constraint values
[[ 0.  -0.1 -0.2]
 [ 0.1  0.  -0.1]
 [ 0.2  0.1  0. ]]
New constraint values (same as lower triangle of above array)
[0.1 0.2 0.1]
Old constraint lower bound
[[0 3 6]
 [1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]]
New constraint lower bound (same as lower triangle of above array)
[1 2 5]

This essentially "flattens" your constraint into a 2D linear matrix.

Maybe, but I don't see how that's avoidable, given the problem here. You have a quadratic number of pairs of x values.

Looping seems unwise here.

@Reinderien: I replaced the 2 loops with itertool.combinations - but how would you avoid it altogether?

You'll want your constraint to scale if the vector x is long. The proper way to do this is feed LinearConstraint sparse matrices:
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse


def make_constraint_array(
    n: int, # The number of decision variables
    dtype: np.dtype = np.int8,
) -> scipy.sparse.sparray:
    # The number of unique constraints
    p = n*(n - 1)//2

    # Sparse index type. Scipy requires this for certain calls.
    itype = np.int32

    # Index (column) pointers for the left-hand CSC array
    decreasing = np.arange(n - 1, -1, -1, dtype=itype)
    sums = decreasing.cumsum(dtype=itype)
    indptr = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=itype)
    indptr[1:] = sums

    # Left (minuend) terms: a column of n-1 ones, then n-2 ones, [...] then 0 ones.
    # "standard" constructor form of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_array.html
    left = scipy.sparse.csc_array((
        np.ones(shape=p, dtype=dtype),  # data
        np.arange(p, dtype=itype),      # indices
        indptr,
    ))

    # Offsets (columns) for the right-hand COO array
    repeat_offsets = np.repeat(a=n - sums[:-1], repeats=decreasing[:-1])

    # Right (subtrahend) diagonal terms
    # scipy.sparse.dia_array is one possible form, but half efficiency of the COO style.
    # "existing data" constructor form of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_array.html
    right = scipy.sparse.coo_array((
        left.data,
        (left.indices, left.indices + repeat_offsets),  # y, x coords
    ))

    return left - right


def demo() -> None:
    print(make_constraint_array(n=6).toarray())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()

[[ 1 -1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0 -1  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0  0 -1]
 [ 0  1 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  1 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  1 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1 -1]]

